telebot handler not being triggered and selenium not working in Python bot
I have two problems.
The first: I'm using the telebot library for Telegram bot development. When I click the "Post" button in the inline keyboard, the callback query handler (post_news) should be triggered, but it isn't working as expected. The callback is not being called when the button is clicked.
The second: I'm using Selenium to scrape news from a website, but it's not working.
Errors:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60076/devtools/browser/f64616b4-7e52-49b3-b36e-6e1f166803af
[17928:15652:1230/001102.559:ERROR:webgpu_decoder_impl.cc(1785)] Failed to query ID3D11Device from ANGLE.
[17928:15652:1230/001104.059:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(426)] [.RendererMainThread-0x112c05804e00]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, 
GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels
[17928:15652:1230/001104.086:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(426)] [.RendererMainThread-0x112c05804e00]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, 
GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels
[17928:15652:1230/001104.109:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(426)] [.RendererMainThread-0x112c05804e00]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, 
GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels
[17928:15652:1230/001104.153:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(426)] [.RendererMainThread-0x112c05804e00]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, 
GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels (this message will no longer repeat)
[7184:19160:1230/001104.370:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(147)] Failed to resolve address for stun4.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
[7184:19160:1230/001104.371:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(147)] Failed to resolve address for stun4.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
[7184:19160:1230/001104.371:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(147)] Failed to resolve address for stun4.l.google.com., errorcode: -105     
[7184:19160:1230/001104.372:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(147)] Failed to resolve address for stun3.l.google.com., errorcode: -105     
[7184:19160:1230/001104.372:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(147)] Failed to resolve address for stun3.l.google.com., errorcode: -105     
[7184:19160:1230/001104.372:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(147)] Failed to resolve address for stun3.l.google.com., errorcode: -105     
[17928:15652:1230/001104.418:ERROR:webgpu_decoder_impl.cc(1785)] Failed to query ID3D11Device from ANGLE.

My code:
class RegionalNewsBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bot = TeleBot(os.getenv("TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN"))
        self.channel_id = os.getenv("TELEGRAM_CHANNEL_ID")
        self.chrome_options = self._configure_chrome_options()

        self._initialize_database()
        self.register_handlers()

        self.current_region = None
        self.current_source = None
        self.current_news = None

    def _configure_chrome_options(self):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        return options


    def _initialize_database(self):
        self.db_connection = sqlite3.connect("sources.db", check_same_thread=False)
        cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sources (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            region TEXT NOT NULL,
            source_name TEXT NOT NULL,
            url TEXT NOT NULL,
            keywords TEXT NOT NULL
        )
        """)
        cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS published_news (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            title TEXT NOT NULL,
            description TEXT,
            link TEXT NOT NULL,
            region TEXT NOT NULL
        )
        """)
        self.db_connection.commit()



    def get_sources_by_region(self, region):
        cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT source_name, url, keywords FROM sources WHERE region = ?", (region,))
        return cursor.fetchall()

   


    def fetch_severinfo_news(self, url, keywords):
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        news_items = []
        articles = soup.select("div", class_="main_content container")
        seen_links = set()  # множество для отслеживания уникальных ссылок
        print(f"Articles found: {len(articles)}")

        for article in articles:
            title_tag = article.find("h5")
            title = title_tag.get_text(strip=True) if title_tag else None

            description_tag = article.find("p")
            description = description_tag.get_text(strip=True) if description_tag else None

            link_tag = article.find('a', href=True)
            link = link_tag['href'] if link_tag else None

            if link in seen_links:
                continue
            seen_links.add(link)

            image_tag = article.find_previous("img")
            image_url = image_tag["src"] if image_tag else None
            
            
            if not title or not link or not description:
                continue  

            if keywords:
                if any(keyword.lower() in (title or '').lower() or keyword.lower() in (description or '').lower() for keyword in keywords):
                    description_with_link = self.embed_link_in_first_verb(description, link) if description else None
                    news_items.append({
                        "title": title,
                        "description": description_with_link,
                        "link": link,
                        "image": image_url,  
                    })
            else:
                description_with_link = self.embed_link_in_first_verb(description, link) if description else None
                news_items.append({
                    "title": title,
                    "description": description_with_link,
                    "link": link,
                    "image": image_url, 
                })


        return news_items



    def fetch_dzen_news(self, url, keywords):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=self.chrome_options)
        driver.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        driver.quit()
        news_items = []
        articles = soup.select('article.news-card__inner-card')
        links = soup.select('a.news-card__link[href]')
        for article, link_tag in zip(articles, links):
            title_tag = article.find('span', class_='news-card__title')
            title = title_tag.get_text(strip=True) if title_tag else None

            description_tag = article.find('span', class_='news-card__annotation')
            description = description_tag.get_text(strip=True) if description_tag else None

            link = link_tag['href']
            if link and not link.startswith("http"):
                link = f"https://dzen.ru{link}"

            if not keywords or any(keyword.lower() in (title or '').lower() or keyword.lower() in (description or '').lower() for keyword in keywords):
                description_with_link = self.embed_link_in_first_verb(description, link) if description else None
                news_items.append({
                    "title": title.rstrip('.'),
                    "description": f"{description_with_link}.",
                    "link": link,
                })

        return news_items

    def preview_news(self, news_items, chat_id):
        print(f"Previewing news: {news_items}")
        self.current_news = news_items
        for idx, news in enumerate(news_items):
            text = f"*{news['title']}*\n\n{news['description']}"
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            post_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f" Post {idx}", callback_data=f"post{idx}")
            markup.add(post_button)
            self.bot.send_message(chat_id, text, reply_markup=markup, parse_mode="Markdown")

    def register_handlers(self):
       
        


                
        @self.bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text in [source[0] for source in self.get_sources_by_region(self.current_region)])
        def select_source(message):
            self.current_source = message.text
            source_info = next((source for source in self.get_sources_by_region(self.current_region) if source[0] == self.current_source), None)
            if source_info:
                source_name, url, keywords = source_info
                keywords_list = keywords.split(',')
                self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Парсинг новостей из {source_name}...")
                if source_name == "Северинфо":
                    news_items = self.fetch_severinfo_news(url, keywords_list)
                elif source_name == "Дзен":
                    news_items = self.fetch_dzen_news(url, keywords_list)
                else:
                    news_items = []

                if news_items:
                    self.preview_news(news_items, message.chat.id)
                else:
                    self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нет подходящих новостей.")
            else:
                self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ошибка: Источник не найден.")



        @self.bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith(f"post"))
        def post_news(call):
            print("ping")
            try:
                idx = int(call.data.split("_")[1])
                news_item = self.current_news[idx]
                
                self.bot.send_message(
                    self.channel_id,
                    f"*{news_item['title']}*\n\n{news_item['description']}",
                    parse_mode="Markdown"
                )
                self.bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Новость опубликована!")
            except Exception as e:
                self.bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, f"Ошибка: {e}")
                print(f"Ошибка при публикации новости: {e}")

                
        @self.bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "↩ Назад")
        def go_back(message):
            start_command(message)        
        
    def run(self):
        print("Бот запущен!")
        self.bot.polling()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = RegionalNewsBot()
    bot.run()


If you have two completely unrelated questions, they should be two different posts. For the former, you could add some details and maybe a screenshot as it is unclear. The second should be more precise than "it's not working", followed by a huge dump of all your code and all your errors. Try to reduce the problem space and only post a minimal non-working example.
